# Kibana: filter events for today

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using Kibana on top of logstash and I want to filter items in the index to today, or the last 24 hours is fine too.

So apparently this requires me to run a [range query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_most_important_queries_and_filters.html) against the underlying ElasticSearch engine that would look like:

```
"range" : {
    "timestamp" : {
        "gte": "now-24h",
        "lte": "now",
    }
}
```

However - I can't put that in the filter box in Kibana 3:

[image]

This is a numeric range query and it doesn't work - but it shows the input box and the idea.

So my question: how can I create a filter that filters the events to a date range in Kibana 3?

Comment: I believed you can use "now-1d/d" for today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it, it's in the top menu:

[image]

Clicking it generates the range filter as can be seen as the 2nd filter on the left.